# ¿Como transmito un archivo mp4 a una webcam con ffmpeg?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Trato de transmitir un video a mi webcam con ffmpeg he encontrado este codigo

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Tengo instalado v4l2-loopback-utils y ffmpeg version 3.4

pero al ejecutarlo me da este error

```
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[v4l2 @ 0x40c4920] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Tengo Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí puedes hacerlo, pero necesitas instalar el driver v4l2loopback:

`sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms && sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`

Después tienes que "alimentar" esa webcam virtual:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Debes revisar que el dispositivo /dev/video0 exista.

Comment: Me sale error

[v4l2 @ 0x2388880] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!

Comment: Pudiste controlar que se creo el dispositivo /dev/video0?